# NullPointerExceptionError

Tags: java, android

This basic app which was given to me as an project should run quite easily is giving me the hardest time.
Well,I commented everything in my activity and still the same error occurs. So I think that the error is somewhere in the xml files. Please help if you can spot the error.And yeah,the main file is pretty big,but please go through it.

Main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<Gallery 
android:id="@+id/gallery1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Length" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="5dp">


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="FROM" android:textColor="#FFFF00"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:clickable="false"  android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="TO      " android:textColor="#FFFF00" android:clickable="false"  android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"     android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="1" 
    />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:layout_width="70dp"

    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b1"
    android:text="2" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/b3"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b2"
    android:text="3" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b4"
    android:layout_width="70dp"

    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="4" />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/b5"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b4"

    android:text="5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b6"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b5"
    android:text="6"  />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b7"

    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="7" />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/b8"
    android:layout_width="70dp"

    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b7"
    android:text="8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b9"

    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b8"
    android:text="9" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">

<Button

    android:id="@+id/bdot"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="." />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b0"
    android:layout_width="70dp"

    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bdot"
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bc"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b0"
    android:text="C" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="hello">Hello World, GurkhaActivity!</string>
<string name="app_name">Gurkha</string>
<string-array name="length">
    <item>Metre</item>
    <item>Centimetre</item>
    <item>Kilometre</item>
</string-array>
    <string-array name="weight">
    <item>Gram</item>
    <item>Kilogram</item>
    <item>Milligram</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

attrs.xml //For Gallery

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="HelloGallery">
    <attr name="android:galleryItemBackground" />
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sanjay.gurkha"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".GurkhaActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat :

```
03-24 01:30:03.729: D/AndroidRuntime(631): Shutting down VM
03-24 01:30:03.769: W/dalvikvm(631): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sanjay.gurkha/com.sanjay.gurkha.GurkhaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at com.sanjay.gurkha.GurkhaActivity.<init>(GurkhaActivity.java:28)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
03-24 01:30:03.939: E/AndroidRuntime(631):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your label above the Main.xml file is just a typo in the question and should be main.xml since I don't think it would compile if that was wrong.

I'm pretty sure the culprit is these lines:

```
EditText et1=(EditText) findViewById(com.sanjay.gurkha.R.id.editText1);

EditText et2=(EditText) findViewById(com.sanjay.gurkha.R.id.editText2);
```

Since these are outside any method they get called when the object is constructed (and before the onCreate method) hence the mention of the constructor (`<init>`) in the stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

The error is in GurkhaActivity.java line 28 in the constructor.

```
at com.sanjay.gurkha.GurkhaActivity.<init>(GurkhaActivity.java:28)
```

Are you calling findViewById() in onCreate() or in the constructor?  It should be in onCreate(). You don't usually mess with the constructor when you override Activity.

Comment: all my `findViewById` are in the `onCreate` itself. Check the edit please.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `findViewById` from your constructor for `GurkhaActivity` (or you have an instance variable initializer that is calling it). Don't do that. You need to call `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` before calls to `findViewById` can be made.

Comment: all my `findViewById` are in the `onCreate` itself. Check the edit please.